# I have canon pixma mg3100

Tags: drivers, printing, libreoffice, canon

I'm running ubuntu 22.04, the operating system sees my printer which is connected by usb. when I go to print from LibreOffice I get the message: Could not start printer. Please check your printer configurations. I have an install cd for the printer, is there any way to get that to work? It worked on previous version 21.10. I'm familiar with ubuntu, and don't know enough. Please, can some one help me?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it is much appreciated, It won't let me to the site  http://localhost:631 without a username and password. I put in what I use to log in to my computer and does not let me in. When I use the command lpstat -t, It shows me this:   scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for MG3100: usb://Canon/MG3100%20series?serial=325CD3&interface=1
MG3100 accepting requests since Mon 11 Jul 2022 07:25:46 PM EDT
printer MG3100 is idle.  enabled since Mon 11 Jul 2022 07:25:46 PM EDT.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

I solved my printer problem. I found answer on youtube.                                                                                                                                       . Then in Terminal I use this command                                                     `sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-7yWtBRYLM&t=200s The printer works great now

Answer (score 0):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab.

From the command line,

```
lpstat -t
```

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: Got into the site, and to the printer settings, It sees the printer canon mg3100, what drivers do i use, the mg3100 is not there, so from the list, what do i choose ?

Comment: Be careful with exact, copy and paste answers on AU, usually there will be some specific changes needed to *directly address* each question...